# Parsing string in java to get it all on one line

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have String that looks like this:

```
String s = "ABC123,DEF,
            TEST,JJJ,
            123456 0
            789123 2
            555555 3"
```

and I want to parse it so it looks like

```
String s = "ABC123,DEF,TEST,JJJ,123456 0 789123 2 555555 3
```

So far what I have done is:

```
String s = s.replaceAll("\\R+",""));
```

this gave me not what I wanted:

```
String s = "ABC123,DEF,TEST,JJJ,123456 0789123 2555555 3
```

This works to an extent but all the numbers are stuck together which doesn't help so I'm at roadblock right now.

Comment: Maybe `s = s.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace line breaks preceded by `,` with an empty string and then chain it to replace just the line breaks with whitespace.

```
s = s.replaceAll(",\\R+","").replaceAll("\\R+"," ");
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
ABC123,DEFTEST,JJJ123456 0 789123 2 555555 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce all whitespaces sequence to one space, then remove the space after commas

```
s.replaceAll("\\R+"," ").replaceAll(", ", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

*`and I want to parse it so it looks like`*
`String s = "ABC123,DEF,TEST,JJJ,123456 0 789123 2 555555 3`

Current string with line terminators.

```
String s = """
       ABC123,DEF,
       TEST,JJJ,
       123456 0
       789123 2
       555555 3
       """;
```

- first replace the line terminators with a space
- then replace the `", "` with a single comma.  No regex needed here.

```
String result = s.replaceAll("\\R+"," ").replace(", ",",");   

System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
ABC123,DEF,TEST,JJJ,123456 0 789123 2 555555 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition appears to be whether or not the line ends with a *comma*, just use a *for-loop*.

```java
String[] strings = s.split("\\R+");
s = "";
for (String string : strings) {
    s += string;
    if (!string.endsWith(",")) s += " ";
}
```

Output

```
ABC123,DEF,TEST,JJJ,123456 0 789123 2 555555 3
```

It's worth noting some outputs will have a trailing white-space character, you can use the *[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())* method for this, or just place an additional check within the *for-loop*.